# ActiveMQ integration with Weblogic

Tags: weblogic, activemq-classic

I have been tasked with integrating ActiveMQ with Weblogic (v 10.3.6.0).

I have downloaded ActiveMQ v 5.10.0, installed it upon the server and browsed to localhost:8161/admin in order to confirm that ActiveMQ is running.

I'm not sure how to progress from here in order to complete my goal. This link:

http://activemq.apache.org/weblogic-integration.html

.. suggests that there are two approaches to deploying ActiveMQ on Weblogic: either deploying a broker as an application or using a J2EE Connector. I'm investigating the latter approach as I have now installed ActiveMQ on the server (which means that I already have a running broker, I assume) but can't find much useful information on the Net about how to do this.

This page:

http://activemq.apache.org/resource-adapter.html

... suggests that it can be done via a JCA Resource Adapter but again does not give any details on how to do it.

If anyone has any advice or guidance, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try this: http://activemq.apache.org/how-to-deploy-activemq-ra-versionrar-to-weblogic.html?

You will have to grab the resource adapter from [maven](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/activemq/activemq-rar/5.10.0/).

Not that your local installation will help you much expect for testing etc. You should deploy AMQ inside WebLogic if you want it to serve as the JMS layer of WebLogic - otherwise a totally standalone installation is fine. But then you're done, and I suspect you want the deployed version non the less.

Comment: Thank you - I hadn't found that page.